# problem of total reload of the ListView when a new element is added to the c++ model in qt

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I created a Message class which must represent the messages of my application, a User class for the different users

```
#ifndef USER_H
#define USER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include "Message.h"
#include"database.h"


class User :public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QList<Message *> messages READ messages WRITE setMessages NOTIFY messagesChanged)
    

public:
    User(int id,const QString number, const QString& name, const QString& lastName, const QString& imageURL, QObject* parent);
    User(QObject* parent);

    const QString &name() const;
     QString Number() const;
    const QString &lastName() const;
    const QString &imageURL() const;
     int ID() const;

    void setImageURL(const QString &newImageURL);

    bool isOnline() const;
    void setIsOnline(bool newIsOnline);

    const QList<Message *> &messages() const;
    void setMessages(const QList<Message *> &newMessages);

    void addMessage(Message* message);
  
    void setMessage(Message *newMessage);
    void resetMessage();

signals:
    
    void messagesChanged();

private:
    int m_ID ;

    QString m_number;
    QString m_name;

    QList<Message*> m_messages;
    Database m_db;
    Message* m_message;


    bool m_isOnline;


};

#endif // USER_H
```

and a ListUser class for the user list. each User has a QList of message that belongs to him, I expose this QList to my QML code:

```
import QtQuick 2.15


Item {
    anchors.left: parent.left; anchors.right: parent.right;
    anchors.bottom: chatInput.top; anchors.top: parent.top;

    ListView{
        id: openedChatList
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 16


        model:Chat.openedChatUser.messages 
        spacing: 8
        clip: true
        highlightFollowsCurrentItem: true
        onCountChanged: {

            Qt.callLater( openedChatList.positionViewAtEnd )
        }

        delegate: ChatBubble{}

        displaced: Transition{
            NumberAnimation{ properties: "x"; from: openedChatList.width/2; duration: 1500; easing.type: Easing.OutBounce; }
        }

    }
}
```

and I have a method in my User Class to add new message to the QList:

```
void User::addMessage(Message *message)
{
   m_messages.append(message);
   emit messagesChanged();
}
```

I have a method that takes the information of a message from the qml and calls the method addMessage. except that when I add a new message to my QList this one is completely reloaded instead of adding only the new element, this reload is visually perceptible and in the event of a large quantity of message in the QList it becomes very very visible when adding a new message

I tried to make another example of ListView with a QML model, when I add an item to this ListView all the items are not reloaded, but for c++ models containing objects like mine, the ListView fully recharges. I really need help I tried a lot of things but none of them worked